# How to remove the unwanted characters from string in objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am having string like this

```
abcdedfd?xyz
adcdefghdfd?red
```

so i wanted to remove the characters after the `?

Comment: did you ever look at methods offered by `NSString` class ? surely not.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *newString = [[yourString componentsBySeparatedByString: @"?"] objectAtIndex: 0];
```

This assuming the string you want to trim is in `NSString *yourString`.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *stryourstring = @"abcdedfd?xyz";
NSArray *arr = [stryourstring componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];
NSString *str = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
```